# Generating duplicate value mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Edited--

Table1 name is ownership_profile
Table2 name is socity_unit

Colum in Table1: NAME and UNIT_ID

Colum in Table2: wings and unit_no

How to join in one table

Comment: What result are you getting, and what result are you expecting? maybe there just is duplicate data in your tables?

Comment: no..... i dont have dublicate value in my table......

Comment: Maybe because your select *, this will select all columns from all tables, you can use o.* to select just from the o table and s.* to select from the s table, what you are effectively doing is s.*, o.* is that what you want

Comment: No one will be able to help if you don't complete your question with more detail on what you're getting and what you're expecting

Comment: how.... to do.... plz edit my query..... i am newbe

Comment: As Abby said can you please provide the sample data, and then what you want to output then we will be more than happy to help?

Comment: Hey I edited my query... now plz solve my quiz

Answer (score 1):

if there are N rows in table socity_unit with the same socity_id (as sid in table ownership_profile) then you will see the cartesian product of socity_unit X ownership_profile.

Thus, for every row in ownership_profile you will get each matching row in socity_unit.

Now, because you have a '*' in the select statement you will get all columns from both tables. If the first table has many-many columns then there is an illusion that the rows are duplicated, till you scroll to the right, in order to see the columns from second table ...

Is this your case?